# iOS: Is it safe to run background task on UIViewController after modal?

Tags: ios, objective-c

On the initial view controller, I declared a retain, nonatomic property for an object which will run a background task and return result using block.

The problem is the initial view controller will modal another view controller before the background task complete, is it safe ?

Comment: Probably, but it would be nice to see some code to make sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's absolutely safe. The only thing I'd like to recommend is to perform result block on main thread.